# If flash message doesn't exist then redirect to home page

Tags: php, symfony

**Scenario:**
I redirect you to message page to show "*Successful*!" message which is coming from `FlashBag`. You hit F5 but get kicked out to home page instead because there is no message to see anymore. Session is cleared. How can I implement this logic?

I guess I should have something like this in message controller just before rendering view:

```
if (flash message == doesn't exist anymore) { redirect to home page }
```

Thanks

**Below is how I redirect users to message controller from another controllers:**

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Successful!');
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('message'));
```

**ROUTER:**

```
message:
    pattern:    /message
    defaults:   { _controller: SeHirBundle:Message:index }
    requirements:
        method: GET
```

**MESSAGE CONTROLLER:**

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SeHirBundle:Default:message.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**TWIG:**

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('message') %}
        <div class="flash-notice">
            {{ flashMessage }}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where is there a question in here?

Comment: You could create an event listener that would check for the flash message on page load and then redirect if it's not present. Check out - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event

Comment: @developerwjk - I can't find what to say to you mate! Thank you Qoop I think that's the way to go in this case.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, now is there a question you need answered?  If so I suggest you post it

Comment: I bet you both can see the question but just want to be awkward, that's all. Be constructive to people, don't be picky. Minipipo1 below gave the answer for the question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your indexAction() in MessageController, you just have to had this condition at the beginning of the method :

```
if (!$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->has('message')) { // Check if there is no Flash messages of type "message"
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage')); // Enter your homepage route here
}
```

This [has() method](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBag.html#method_has) of the FlashBag allows you to check if there is any FlashMessages still not displayed.

Comment: Thank you. Woks perfectly fine. +1